# Basic C++ segfault when using new and passing a pointer

Tags: c++

Can somebody please explain the segfault here:

```
class foo
{
  private:
    some_class *test_;


    void init_some_class(some_class*);
    void use_class();
 }

 foo::foo()
 {
     //test_ = new some_class(variables, variables); //THIS WOULD WORK
 }

 void foo::init_some_class(some_class *tmp)
 {
   tmp = new some_class(variables,variables);
 }

 void foo::use_class()
 {
   test_->class_function() //THIS SEGfaults
 }
```

I would call the funtion via init_some_class(test_);  If I use new in the constructor then the test_->class_function() works fine.  It only seems to segfault when I use new outside of the class constructor and try and pass the pointer through the function

Comment: You are assigning to temporary pointer in `init_some_class`, either return the pointer or use a pointer to pointer as the parameter. Better still assign to `test_` as was probably your intention.

Comment: Did you mean to assign to `test_` instead of assigning to `tmp` in `init_some_class`?

Comment: I meant to use tmp as the init_some_class function performs lots of tasks on a particular class so I'd like to pass in a pointer and do operations on the class that it point to

Comment: So the new inside of the init_some_class scope is only within that function.... I thought that I'd passed the actual pointer into the function with the call

Comment: You aren't actually assigning to `test_` anywhere. `test_->class_function()` is undefined behaviour if `test_` does not point to a valid constructed object.

Comment: `int x; int y = 6; printf("%i\n", x);` <-- why doesn't this print 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write in `init_some class()` :

```
tmp = new some_class(variables,variables);
```

you are in fact storing the new pointer in the parameter that is passed by value.  But this parameter is local to the function and lost as soon as the function returns.

So if you call somewhere `init_some class(test_)`  the value of `test_` is transferred to `tmp`, but the changed `tmp` remains local to the function.  You therefore get a segfault beause `test_` remains uninitialized.

**Possible solutions:**

A simple solution to the described use case could be to pass the parameter by reference:

```
void foo::init_some_class(some_class *& tmp)  // note the &
{
   tmp = new some_class(variables,variables);
}
```

With this definition, when calling `init_some class(test_)`, the original `test_` pointer gets modified.

Another solution could be to have the `init_some_class()` change directly the `test_` member.  You'd then no longer need a parameter.

Comment: Ok so I need to instead just return the pointer that I create with new to test_?  (or do some kind of pointer to pointer)

Comment: @RossW I just completed the answer with some options.  Returning the pointer is also a possibility (if you can somehow ensure that nobody will call the function without taking care of the return value)